# How does pyspark RDD countByKey() count?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

Before posting this question I searched the community and referred pyspark docs, but I am still not able to understand how its counting.

```
sc.parallelize((('1',11),('1'),('11'),('11',1))).countByKey().items()
```

output:

```
dict_items([('1', 3), ('11', 1)])
```

I am not able to interpret the output. Why is it counting '1' as 3 and '11' as 1?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you call `countByKey()`, the key will be be the first element of the container passed in (usually a `tuple`) and the value will be the rest.

You can think of the execution to be roughly functionally equivalent to:

```
from operator import add

def myCountByKey(rdd):
    return rdd.map(lambda row: (row[0], 1)).reduceByKey(add)
```

The function maps each row in your `rdd` to the first element of the row (the key) and the number `1` as the value. Finally we reduce adding the values together for each key, to get the count.

Let's try this on your example:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize((('1',11),('1'),('11'),('11',1)))
myCountByKey(rdd).collect()
#[('1', 3), ('11', 1)]
```

The "extra" `'1'` is coming from the third element `('11')`. Mapping this row to `(row[0], 1)` yields `('1', 1)`. In this case, `row[0]` is the first character in the string.

You may expected this to behave as if the third element were the tuple `('11',)`.

```
rdd = sc.parallelize((('1',11),('1',),('11',),('11',1)))
rdd.countByKey().items()
#[('1', 2), ('11', 2)]
```

The takeaway is that you *must* include the comma if you want to specify a key with no value.

Answer (score 0):

it's like if a default split is done to obtain array of tuple:
(('1',11),('1'),('11'),('11',1))
will become
(('1',11),('1',''),('1','1'),('11',1))
countByKey will result :
[('1','3'),('11','1')]